# How can I mount my surge protector using these holes

Tags: organization, hardware, fastener

I've had this surge protector since I was in high school. I looked at the bottom of the surge protector and noticed some holes which I assume are used to mount the surge protector to something.

[image: surge protector]

There is a panel between the two rear legs of my desk that has a bunch of holes. I think it is made to mount stuff to it.

[image: desk mounting panel]

What can I use to mount the surge protector to this panel? Probably using cable ties. I could just wrap the whole surge protector using the cable ties. But that will probably look more sloppy and I would like to use the holes if that is what they are made for.

Is there some sort of standard fastener that makes use of the holes on the surge protector? I don't recall if the surge protector came with anything.

If it helps, I believe this is the surge protector that I have: [Amazon product link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01AZX6RZI)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lawrence posted the right answer 4 hours ago. I just want to add more clarification, and when I started typing this clarification as a comment on Lawrence's answer, it got too long.

The slot holds onto the HEAD of the screw, nail, or bolt. (In your case, a bolt will work best.) You put the bolt head into the circular part of the slot, then slide it to the left or the right. That locks the bolt head into the slot.

If you want to mount your power strip horizontally, so it doesn't hang off the bottom of that metal sheet you found, here are some steps you can follow:

1. Put a bolt into each of the slots (head first).
2. Slide each bolt towards the outside of its slot. That is, if the bolt is on the left side of the power strip, slide it to the left; and if it's on the right side of the power strip, slide it to the right.
3. Place your power strip against that metal sheet on the back of your desk. Align all the threaded bolt shafts so they go through a hole in the metal sheet.
4. Move around to the back of that metal sheet. All the threaded shafts should be sticking through. Screw a nut onto each one to secure it. They only have to be finger-tight, so you don't need a wrench. You could even use wingnuts to make it easier.

Comment: Thanks so much. When I was laying in bed about to fall asleep I had a moment of enlightenment and thought that it should be for the head of a bolt/screw because of its shape. So these answers confirmed my theory. Also, thank you very much for reading my mind about wanting to mount it horizontally. That is very helpful. I'll accept your answer since you went into a lot of detail.

Comment: Screws with sunken heads work best for these things. Try and re-adjust the depth of the screw until you get a nice tight fit.

Answer (score 2):

In each of the 4 holes, the opening in the middle is for a screw or nail.

Turn the devise sideways (rotate it 90 degrees), put the head of a screw through the hole, then let the device slide down a little so that the screw head is wedged onto the slender (top) part of the hole.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend tracing the location of the holes onto a piece of paper then using that to transfer the measurements to the surface where you're mounting the surge protector.